# Найти все записи JSON по определенному значению

Tags: php, json

У меня есть JSON-массив данных

Пример массива:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "ЮЛ": {
        "ИНН": "7203171935",
        "ОГРН": "1067203020268",
        "НаимСокрЮЛ": "ТСН \"МЕЛЬНИКАЙТЕ, 100\"",
        "НаимПолнЮЛ": "ТОВАРИЩЕСТВО СОБСТВЕННИКОВ НЕДВИЖИМОСТИ \"МЕЛЬНИКАЙТЕ, 100\"",
        "ДатаОГРН": "2006-02-16",
        "Статус": "Действующее",
      }
    },
    {
      "ЮЛ": {
        "ИНН": "7203251330",
        "ОГРН": "1107232033149",
        "НаимСокрЮЛ": "ТСН \"СОСЕДИ\"",
        "НаимПолнЮЛ": "ТОВАРИЩЕСТВО СОБСТВЕННИКОВ НЕДВИЖИМОСТИ \"СОСЕДИ\"",
        "ДатаОГРН": "2010-09-24",
        "Статус": "Действующее",
      }
    },
    {
      "ЮЛ": {
        "ИНН": "7203186956",
        "ОГРН": "1067200019996",
        "НаимСокрЮЛ": "НП \"ЦКУЖ \"АЛЬТЕРНАТИВА\"",
        "НаимПолнЮЛ": "НЕКОММЕРЧЕСКОЕ ПАРТНЕРСТВО \"ЦЕНТР КООРДИНАЦИИ УПРАВЛЕНИЯ ЖИЛЬЕМ \"АЛЬТЕРНАТИВА\"",
        "ДатаОГРН": "2006-12-21",
        "Статус": "Действующее",
      }
    },
```

Мне необходимо вывести все найденные записи, только по определенному ИНН. Как я могу это сделать?

Моя попытка выглядит так:

```php
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($array, TRUE)),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    echo "<table class='table table-bordered'><h3>Таблица</h3>";

    foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            if ($key['ИНН'] === $inn) {
                echo "<tr><th scope='row'>$key</th></tr>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<th scope='col'>$key</th><td colspan='3'>$val</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: `foreach (json_decode($array, TRUE)['items'] ...` `if ($val['ЮЛ']['ИНН'] == $inn)`

Comment: @ArchDemon, Если я правильно вас понял, поправьте если я ошибся:          foreach (json_decode($data, true)['items'] as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['ЮЛ']['ИНН'] == $inn) {
            echo "<th scope='col'>$key</th><td colspan='3'>$val</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table>"; Но я вывожу пустоту

Comment: `$val` - это массив и просто так вставить его в строку не получится. Нужно хотя бы так `" . print_r($val['ЮЛ'], true) . "`